# Pointer to function that returns pointer to same function type

Tags: c, function-pointers

Is it possible in C to have a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to the same type of function? i.e. a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a function that returns a pointer to a function that... etc etc.

A function pointer with int return type is:

```
int (*fp)(void);
```

So I guess a function pointer with function pointer to *that* would be

```
typedef int (*fp)(void);
fp (*pfp)(void);
```

But a pointer to a function that returns a function of the same type would have... an infinite recursive declaration? i.e. one would never be able to write the first typedef.
Is that correct?

I'm thinking a workaround would be to actually return a void pointer then cast that to the function pointer type maybe? e.g.

```
typedef void * (*fp)(void)

void * stateWork(void) {return &nextStateWork}

machine () {
    fp = &stateWork;
    state = (fp)(*fp)();
}
```

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Fab, thanks. Have added my vote to close although I was searching on SO for a while before I posted as I was certain someone else must have asked this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in the first part, you cannot have a directly recursive type in C.

But your workaround runs afoul of UB:

data-pointers and function-pointers are fundamentally different types, roundtrip-conversion is not guaranteed:
Just use any old function-type for function pointers, they are all mutually round-trip convertible.

Aside: Making `void*` and function-pointers compatible is a common extension mentioned in the standard.
POSIX, Windows and MacOS do it:

> #### J.5.7 [common extensions] Function pointer casts
>
> 1 A pointer to an object or to void may be cast to a pointer to a function, allowing data to
>   be invoked as a function (6.5.4).
>   2 A pointer to a function may be cast to a pointer to an object or to void, allowing a
>   function to be inspected or modified (for example, by a debugger) (6.5.4).

Comment: Common in the context of desktops maybe... ;) Thanks for the added info though!

Comment: iOS is MacOS and Android is Linux and Windows Phone is Windows. :)

Comment: Also, all function pointers are mutually round-trip convertible, so you could use some dummy function pointer type as the return type.

Comment: @Deduplicator Is that from the C99 std?

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev True, but then there's the millions of devices that have no OS, the compilers for which stick strictly to the standard, without most extensions.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Was already in my answer. Toby: It's C11.